# Shopware 6 how to build administration in dev mode

Tags: shopware

In the .env file I have *APP_ENV="dev"* but that seems it doesn't affect building assets when building administration.

```
> administration@1.0.0 build
> mode=production webpack
```

In shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration there is webpack.config.js which works with some process.env."nameOfVariable" variables but where to set them ?

Thanks in advance.